# WPF button content is being empty when underline mnemonic is used

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

We are experiencing some strange issue in our WPF application with Caliburn.Micro as MVVM framework. We have a simple button in our dialog window, which is mapped to a property in the view model.

```
<Button x:Name="CloseButton"
        Margin="6"
        MinWidth="85"
        Width="Auto"
        Style="{DynamicResource StandardButton}"
        Content="{Binding CloseButtonText}"
```

And we have it set in the code-behind.

```
public string CloseButtonText => "_Close";
```

"_" is used for a mnemonic, so users can click the button with ALT + C shortcut (http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/01/061004.html).
The problem is that sometimes when we open the dialog first time, the button is empty. Second time it binds the text successfully.
The issue DOES NOT happen when I remove underscore from the text.

```
public string CloseButtonText => "Close";
```

The issue does not happen also if I directly write "_Close" in my XAML code. However, I need to have a property to change it from some other places.
I tried to have a simple property and move initialization to constructor/OnActivate method with no luck. The same issue is happening in that case too.

Does anyone have an idea why is it happening? Why is it happening ONLY when "_" is used? Any ideas?

Comment: Does the button still respond to the mnemonic when it appears blank?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: That's too bad. The mnemonic does increase the height of the tallest character on the button. Sometimes instead of clipping text that is too tall for a component would just not display. I thought the mnemonic would still work though so it is probably something else.

Comment: I think the button's content is just empty. It seems to me an issue with WPF binding. But I don't understand why the same binding always works with strings which do not contain mnemonic underscore, but fails to work with the ones which contain it...

Comment: You might want to try some techniques from here: https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/ to see if you can find an issue in the binding.

Comment: Could you bind it to `<AccessText>` inside `<Button>`?